# Why are Rails assets not isolated between models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have these a coffeescript file for a model `entree` that just instanciates a class in another coffeescript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
  ch = new CepageHandling
  ch.handleKeyPress()
```

The `handlePress` function captures `keyup` events on a control.

I have another model `vin` where I want to enable the same feature. I'm surprised to see I don't need to do anything (it already has the same html), it's already working, even though the coffeescript for the `vin` model is completely empty. I assume that the created javascript for `entree` gets called even when I'm not on this page.

I have seen the same behavior with `scss` files, where style defined for one model gets applied to others if the descriptors match. Can someone explain (or point to some article) if this is normal behavior that assets are not isolated in rails? I really have a hard time grasping how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default manifest files (`application.js`, etc) do `require_tree .` which will load all files on all pages, concat them all together in production, etc. If you want things to be isolated you'll need to put a test in your `ready` handler to skip this code in some cases, or you'll need more manifests (and not use `application.js` for example) to silo your code per page. I suggest you read every word of the [asset pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) very carefully... required reading!

Comment: I've read it but I must admit I may have skipped the part about this. thx!

Comment: Generally for a complex application you'll find you need more than just a single manifest. It works ok to just put a test on body id or something at first, but as you get a real app forming you'll probably want different packages for different areas of the site (`billing.js`, `billing.css`, `admin.js`, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the manifest file **application.js**, more precisely in this line of code:

```
//= require_tree .
```

What this means is that all **.js** files contained inside the **/assets/javascripts/** folder would be loaded to your views.
As your **entree.js** is already loaded and using the **JQuery document ready function**, it searches for the rules of your file inside all of your views.
This means that all of your pages that contains this **ch** element will get the same behavior.